# Java Virtual Machine Launcher : A JNI Error with Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, window, spring-bean

I use Windows10 Pro 32bit ENG, EclipseEE Mars, Java 8_66. If I want create a easy bean project with Spring and run it it show me a error in Windows dialog. When I enter this dialog it generated exception.

```
Java Virtual Machine Launcher - Error : 
A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try it again.
```

I have in CLASSPATH : Apache *.jars

```
•commons-logging-1.2.jar
•commons-logging-1.2-javadoc.jar
```

Spring *.jars

```
•spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
•spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
•spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
•spring-aspects-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
•spring-context-support-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
•spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
•spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
•spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
•spring-expression-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar
```

I have the tested Java 8_60 vs Spring 4.1.5, Java 8_66 vs Spring 4.1.5 or 4.2.2.

KlientMetaTest.java

```
package klient;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import server.ServerVypis;
public class KlientMetaTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/Beans.xml");
        ServerVypis obj = (ServerVypis) context.getBean("mujSpring");                           //  id beanu
        obj.getMessage();   
    }
}
```

ServerVypis.java

```
package server;
public class ServerVypis {
    private String message;
    public void setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message; }
    public void getMessage(){
        System.out.println("Zde je tvuj Spring vypis  : " + message);   }
}
```

beans.xml which is in /META-INF/ folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
   <bean id="mujSpring" class="server.ServerVypis">
       <property name="message" value="Vypis z \META-INF\Bean.xml"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Exception which was showing in console :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved. After I install Windows10, it broke my access to folders when I have save the external jars of frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem.

I made some changes in my pom.xml.  Ff you are using the dependency of javax mail as well aws sdk then make sure that javax mail should be declare before the aws sdk's.

If you change the sequence then it will show the above error as it's loading jars in wrong sequence.As this worked in mine case, Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Pay attention to readability by formatting your answer better.